# Why can't we manipulate objects passed to component via @input() in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

I recently upgraded my app from angular 7 to angular 11.
Everything was working fine and then I implemented angular universal to enable server side rendering.

After implementing server side rendering i got lots of error saying "Can't change readonly 'xyz' member of object [Object Object]"

All these members are from object that i have paaased to child component from parent component via @input()

**My Questions**

1. Is it wrong to manipulate objects passed as Input
2. Why is it breaking for Angular universal (server side rendering) and not for client side rendering

Here's one such component

```
export class BannerComponent {

  @Input() banners : Offer[]
  constructor(private analyticService : AnalyticService) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.banners) {
      this.banners.forEach(banner => {
        if(!banner.bannerImage.startsWith("http"))
          banner.bannerImage = environment.imageHost + banner.bannerImage;
      })
    }    
  }

  recordEvent(banner : Offer) {
    this.analyticService.eventEmitter(banner.category.name, "Click on banner", banner.offerDetail + "-" + banner.merchant.name, AnalyticService.AVG_AFFILIATE_CLICK_VALUE);
  }

}
```

Here's my offer class

```
import { Store } from "./store";
import { Category } from "./category";

export class Offer {
    
    id: number;
   
    merchant: Store;
   
    offerDetail: string;
   
    link: string;
   
    openExternal: boolean;
   
    logoPath: string;
   
    lastDate: Date;
   
    banner: boolean;
   
    bannerImage: string;

    category : Category;
    offerDescription?: string;
}
```

Store and Category are another two models

Comment: Are you able to run `ng build --aot --prod` ?

Comment: Can you show the definition for the `Offer` class?

Comment: @OwenKelvin will let you know by today evening

Comment: @David see edit

Comment: Is the banners attribute in the template provided by an Observable?

Comment: @WillAlexander yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding question 1:

The short answer is yes, you should avoid manipulating data from the parent component in child components.

This is because in Angular, data flows from parent to child components, and that data flows unidirectionally, which is somewhat hinted at in the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-child-component).

In your case, you are modifying the parent component's data.

Consider this example:

```
@Component({
   template: `<app-banner-component [banners]="parentBanners"></app-banner-component>`
})
class ParentComponent {
    parentBanners: Offer[] = {...};
}
```

After `ngOnChanges` was called, the `parentBanners` values will also have their `bannerImage` changed. This is because the array is not copied, but rather passed in by reference, so any changes made to the array in the child component will also apply to the parent component.

Because change detection runs from parent components to child components, this may lead to the dreaded ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked error, as explained in [this video](https://youtu.be/O47uUnJjbJc?t=113).

To work around this, make a copy of your array, for example, like this:

```
@Input() set banners (values: Offer[]) {
    this._banners = values.map(offer => ({...offer}));
}
get banners(): Offer[] {
    return this._banners;
}

private _banners : Offer[];
```

Regarding 2, I have no experience with Angular Universal. My speculation would be that it enforces data flow much more strictly, and refactoring might resolve the issue.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but found it much convincing